# micro_ros_agent failing to connect to Raspberry Pi RP2040 with error: 13

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I’m trying to implement micro ROS on the Pololu 3pi+ 2040 mobile robot. The 3pi+ 2040 has a Raspberry Pi 2040 microcontroller.

I'm currently running Humble in a Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.15.0-67-generic VM guest in UTM on an Intel Mac.

I’ve successfully compiled the Raspberry Pi Pico implementation of micro ROS and read it’s topic according to the instructions here: https://robofoundry.medium.com/raspberry-pi-pico-ros2-via-micro-ros-actually-working-in-1-hr-9f7a3782d3e3

The problem begins when I’ve loaded the Pico uf2 file on the 3pi+ 2040. Reading from the serial port looks similar to the output from the Pico, but the actual agent dies with error code 13 even though I’m running with sudo.

**Does anyone know how to debug in this scenario? I am looking for next steps, if possible.**

The actual output of mico ROS agent is as follows:
bash ~/start_micro-ros-agent.sh
[1679288574.823863] error    | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | open device error      | device: /dev/ttyACM0, errno: 13. Please re-run with superuser privileges.
Error while starting serial agent!

Where start_micro-ros-agent.sh contains:more ~/start_micro-ros-agent.sh
sudo micro-ros-agent serial --dev /dev/ttyACM0 --baudrate=115200 -v6

At the very least this error message is spurious because I am running with root privileges.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413591/micro_ros_agent-failing-to-connect-to-raspberry-pi-rp2040-with-error:-13/) by [Peter Klemperer](https://answers.ros.org/users/142457/peter-klemperer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure why, but rebuilding the micro ros agent from source works. The snap version doesn't work for this application.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Klemperer](https://answers.ros.org/users/142457/peter-klemperer/) with karma: 16 on 2023-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0